# Can I grow strawberries in Lagos Nigeria?

Tags: strawberries

I just bought these strawberry seeds from aliexpress. And while I am awaiting their arrival, I thought it would be good to find out if strawberries can grow on any soil.

Though I've not heard anyone say anything about that. Some think it can't grow in Lagos Nigeria.

Can anyone with experience in strawberry farming tell me if its possible to grow the plant in Lagos Nigeria specifically?

And if not possible, I would like a sound explanation why they cannot grow here. Thanks.

Comment: what type of strawberries?

Comment: I really don't know because the seeds hasn't arrived. I do know there are some types; June bearing,  ever bearing and all kinds. But since I've not seen them nor do i know the difference, i really can't tell. I'm willing to learn though so I'll appreciate some enlightenment if you can.

Comment: some need colder weather than others, and some need hotter.

Comment: I would recommend varieties suited to your climate and soil. It looks like your climate is similar to the southern half of Brazil's. You might see which strawberries they grow there. What kind of soil do you have?

Comment: I think we have partly sand, and partly loamy soil in Lagos Nigeria. Not so sure about soil types sha. I'm just using the little knowledge in agricultural Science to guess. Is there anyway to check which type.?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you will be able to grow strawberries!!  I've never grown strawberries from seed, just from starts.  Where will you be planting these seeds?  I think you should begin by starting them in flats, small tiny pots of POTTING SOIL.  As they grow larger put them in larger pots...for instance: Plant the seeds in 1"X 1"seed starting flats (use potting soil from the store, it is sterilized and there is much more information available on this site).  When roots start coming out of the drain holes, up pot them into 2"X 2" with POTTING SOIL. When they get large enough then transplant them into 4" X 4" pots with potting soil.  When they show roots though the drainage hole then you can harden them off to be able to be planted in the garden.  Start taking them out for half an hour, the next couple of days allow them an hour, the next couple of days allow them 3 hours...after a few weeks of hardening you will be able to plant them in your garden.  Please make raised plant beds...not with wood, concrete but just double dig down at least a foot adding decomposed organic matter.  The bed should be a few feet higher than the original surface at this point.  Dig trenches 6" X 6" at the foot of these beds to collect rain water and direct it where you want the excess water to go.  Use a piece of plywood to compact the soil a bit on the top of the bed (get on top of the plywood and using your weight jump up and down)...then plant your strawberries.  Now is a good time to use a bit of fertilizer but make sure the Nitrogen is lower than the Phosphorus and Potassium in percentage otherwise you will not get reproductive growth.  Strawberries.

If you are planting in pots use STERILIZED STORE BOUGHT POTTING SOIL.  Water well and allow to dry before watering again. No rocks or gravel or anything at the bottom of the pot.  Make sure there are drainage holes. Same type of watering for planting in the garden. Water deeply and allow to dry before the next watering. Strawberries are supposedly only good for 2 seasons then need to be replaced with new plants in new soil, new location.  I am trying my third year in the same location.  Still looking great but I'm not in commercial production, either.  Lots of problems with disease and reduced production. The only time I ever use straw is with strawberries.  It is a great barrier between the fruits and soil and will mitigate botrytis, grey mold, very common, very normal.  As soon as fruits ripen, get them off the plant so others will ripen.  I recommend everbearing versus June bearing.

Comment: Okay Stormy, thanks for the response. I would have replied earlier, but got pressured down by work.                             But do you think climate is a barrier to the success of the fruit. Then secondly, if i were to not plant through seeds, is there anyway to import plants because its scarce in our country here much less Lagos state. Then lastly, is there anyway to differentiate between everbearing from june bearing seeds, or from plants. Thanks for your quick response once again.